# Adjusting a Cronjob Every Time It Runs?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I am attempting to schedule a two-stage backup process for Jira which I've scripted.

First a Jira backup must be triggered, it then takes 20-30minutes to be created and available for download.

Triggering a backup can only be done every 48 hours beginning from the point that the backup is finished & available, which seems to take 20-30 minutes from triggering.

Second, a jira backup can be downloaded within 24hours after the backup is created.

My issue is if I schedule a cron for the trigger and then schedule the download say an hour later eg.

```
0 4 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh triggerbackup
0 5 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh downloadbackup
```

The first backup is fine, but the next time it will error as the crontab will execute 20-30minutes short of the 48hour limit.

Both cron tasks would need to "slip" lets say an hour to be safe, in order to be outside the 48hour window each time the script runs eg.

first time

```
0 4 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh triggerbackup
0 5 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh downloadbackup
```

second time

```
0 5 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh triggerbackup
0 6 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh downloadbackup
```

third time

```
0 6 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh triggerbackup
0 7 */2 * * /bin/bash jira.sh downloadbackup
```

etc.

Personally, I'd just delay the frequency but I don't make the rules. I'm thinking there may be an easy solution I can't see atm but eitherway it's an interesting problem I've never encountered.. Any ideas how to achieve this via cron?

Comment: That's horrible. Consider figuring out what is causing the hard limit instead.

Comment: Yup, far as I can tell It's just an Atlassian thing to reduce the amount of backups. I acknowledge 48hr Jira backups is a bit excessive, but still could be the worst backup policy I've seen. I do not see an answer other than reducing frequency eg. every 3 days or more.

Comment: Perhaps I just use a different version, but can't you setup Jira to do automatic backups, and then have a script that makes it available whenever a new file is located in the backup location?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `cron` use `at`. At the end of the backup script schedule the next backup for 49 hours later, and schedule the download script.

```
at now + 49 hours <<EOF
/bin/bash jira.sh triggerbackup
EOF
at now + 1 hours <<EOF
/bin/bash jira.sh downloadbackup
EOF
```